# How can a public method return a private type?

Tags: java, oop, visibility

Why is it possible to return a `private` nested class from a `public` method in a `public` class? Shouldn't the compiler complain about the return type's visibility being less than the method?

```
public final class Outer {
    private static final class Configurator {
        private Configurator() {
        }
    }

    public static Configurator configure() {
        return new Configurator();
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't possible. Please post some code. I assume the method's signature _returns_ a public interface (or similar) whereas the method's implementation returns a private subclass of that interface. This is allowed.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose: It *is* possible, surprisingly. Feels like a Java design flaw to me. (C# doesn't allow it.)

Comment: Ah, ok. I see. Simple technical explanation: At the scope of this method's declaration, the (private) class is visible and therefore can be used as a return type in the method's signature. However, you can only call this method from inside this class. Code in every other class cannot invoke this method due to not being able to access that private class.

Comment: @JonSkeet So what would happen if I called the `configure()` method from an external package? Would the method not be visible?

Comment: @JonSkeet You are right. I thought from the _client's_ point of view.

Comment: @Locutus: I honestly don't know. I suspect it will be visible, but have an *effective* type of `Object`. Will check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *can* call such a method from outside the class, but only if you are happy to throw away the result.

```
public class TestClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Outer.configure(); // this is valid
  }
}
```

or if you are happy to refer to the result as an `Object`:

```
public class TestClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Object o = Outer.configure(); // this is valid
  }
}
```

The compiler allows this because it doesn't break any rules of Java. `Object` is simply the only publicly available superclass of your private class.

I doubt there are many practical uses for this pattern. If you wish to return an opaque object, that's better done by passing back a public class with no public methods, since you can at least type-check it when passed back into classes that need to use it.

Comment: +1 - Indeed, your 2nd example illustrates that there can be uses for this (seemingly) anomalous language feature.

Comment: Actually [there *is* an important practical use](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26038350/2711488)

Comment: @Holger Unless I misunderstand your point, then that's exactly what I'm saying in the final paragraph of my answer. That this pattern could be used to create opaque objects, but there are better ways to do it.

Comment: @Holger I think we are talking about slightly different things. You are talking about the general case, whereas I was focussing more on this specific case (i.e. where `Object` is the only public super class). Hence the differences in our responses. You get a +1 from me though, as you make some valid points.

Comment: @Duncan: right, I was more general here as the OPs question was “Why is it possible …”. But indeed, in this specific example there is little sense in using this possibility.

Answer (score 2):

There is a strict requirement that `interface` methods must be `public`. So when the method returning a non-`public` type fulfills an `interface` contract it *must be* `public`:

```
class Foo implements Supplier<NonPublicType> {
  public NonPublicType get() { // must be public !
    …
  }
}
```

---

Further, it is still possible to call this method from outside the package if the declaring class and the method are `public`. But the result has to be assigned to an accessible super type of the non-`public` class if it’s going to be used. E.g. if `NonPublicType` from the example above implements `CharSequence` you could say `CharSequence cs=foo.get();` outside the package (if we change `Foo` to `public`).

Note that the method in question might override a super class method which returns a `public` type and return a more specific non-`public` type (aka [Covariant return type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type)). That method might be called from classes within the same package making use of the more specific type.

Answer (score 0):

A nested class is a member of its enclosing class, so just like in singleton design pattern, when you call the public method to get the private static instance only through that method, it is also possible to call a private static class as a member or one of its methods.
The reason you nested it is probably one of the following:

- Logically grouping classes that are only used in one place
- To increases encapsulation
- To get more readable and maintainable code

For example if it were private, you can't say:

```
OuterClass.StaticNestedClass nestedObject =
 new OuterClass.StaticNestedClass();
```

So you need a public method to access it in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It's entirely possible and makes sense, although a short practical example is rather difficult. The private class may be returned in place of any of its superclasses. Object has been mentioned here, but it doesn't have to be Object. This example is a little on the wacky side, but it works.

```
abstract class Super {
    abstract void zipper();
}

final class Outer {

    private static final class Configurator extends Super {
        private Configurator() {
        }

        @Override
        void zipper() {
            System.out.println("Zip!");
        }
        public void zoomer() {
            System.out.println("Zoom!");
        }

    }

    public static Configurator configure() {
        return new Configurator();
    }

}

public final class PublicPrivate {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        /* Outer.configure returns an instance of Configurator, 
            a subclass of Super */
        final Super = Outer.configure();
        /* Configurator.zoomer() is not available, 
            because Configurator is private */
        // o.zoomer(); /* Uncomment this line and the compile will fail */
        /* But Super.zipper() is available,
            in the form in which Configurator overrid it */
        o.zipper();
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that's because how you're going to deal with the object in the callee can be deferred until the last moment. For example, suppose

```
private static class X{

}

public static MyClass.X getX() {
    return new MyClass.X();
}
```

then from another class, I do something like

```
public void get() {
    System.out.println(MyClass.getX());
}
```

I don't need to know what type X is here because println just wants its toString(), which is inherited from Object.

Another example

```
private static class X implements Serializable{

}

public static MyClass.X getX() {
    return new MyClass.X();
}
```

In this case, I don't know X, but I know it's Serializable, so I can do something like

```
public void get() {
    Serializable x= MyClass.getX();
}
```

What I can't do, of course, is to use the type X from outside MyClass, but until I really need it, it's just another instance of Object